# Pywinauto Gets the contents of AfxFrameOrView42？

Tags: pywinauto

When I was doing automation, I met the class AfxFrameOrView42,

 
but pywinauto's document does not have this class, how can I get the contents of AfxFrameOrView42?

Comment: Try `backend="uia"` when creating Application object. More details about backends: [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: Any more details?

Comment: Thank you very much,My English is not very good。I can only read a part of the document。so~~~~

Comment: Did you try `Inspect.exe`?

Comment: Huh, I'm not a native speaker too and I thought the guide was written by pretty simple words. Maybe you can tell which part of the guide is the most unclear to you?

Comment: I don't know where to download inspect.exe
For example, how to wait for a window to disappear or appear。I can't find a way I can understand in the doc

Comment: The second paragraph of the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) contains link to the GitHub repo with `Inspect.exe` and other tools. Waiting for long operations are described here: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html